# Segregating title into words and searching in a title

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to automate an Excel file which has title in both A and B columns and I have to search each word from A within B. If any words matches then I need to paste it after B column which is available (C, D, ...) at the same row.

I was using the below code for which I will be segregating the words manually in a separate column of column A title and searching it in column B:

```
Sub macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim col As Range, cell1 As Range, a As String, b As String, i As Integer
Set col = Range("KW[KW1]")
Dim target, cell As Range
Sheets("Data").Select
Set target = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
Dim term, tag As String
    For Each cell1 In col
    a = cell1.Value

    term = a
    tag = a

        For Each cell In target
            b = cell.Value

          If Module1.ExactWordInString(b, a) Then
                For i = 1 To 15
                    If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, i).Value = tag
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

        End If

        Next cell
    Next cell1
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm expecting the output:

```
Column A          Column B                    Column C  Column D
Title 1           Title 2       
XXX YYY zzz aaa   asdbfjk XXX yyy sfkbvskdf     XXX       yyy
```

Obviously its taking so much time, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Can you post an image or example of the layout and the desired outcome?

Comment: Look at the Split() function.

Comment: `Range("B65536")` makes your code less portable -- why hardwire in an obsolete limit on the number of rows? Also -- those nested loops look like they will be slow. It would be better to se a dictionary rather than a large number of linear searches.

Comment: @ExcelHero sorry i couldn't able to add image, hence i have add an example. Hope this is fine :)

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for heads up. I know this is taking much time, could you please explain me how to use the dictionary here.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewD I'm trying it :)

Comment: @LingaGuru What is the function `ExactWordInString`? That is the function which could potentially be replaced by a dictionary lookup. Something in which strings extracted from `a` can be looked up against a dictionary created from Column B

Comment: Do you only care about titles on the same row? Like does each title in Column A have to be searched against every title in Column B?

Comment: @JohnColeman may be but i don't how to use dictionary lookup and how it works could you please explain me how can i use it here.

Comment: Yes @JNevill but column A title should be split-ed into words then each words needs to searched in columns B

Comment: Yes to which part? Cell A2 is only compared to Cell B2... or Cell A2 has to be compared to every cell in column B? I believe it's the second, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: If there is a match for something in column A against something in column B -- where should the data in column C,D etc. go -- the row from A or the one from B? Your code suggests the latter -- but what if several different rows in A have parts that match against the same row in B? It seems that your code might overwrite data in C

Comment: @JNevill Only cell A2 have to be compared with B2 only not the entire column B.

Comment: @JohnColeman If the column C,D is already filled then it will go to the next column. It wont replace any filled cells in the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what has been discussed and building on what MathewD suggested using the split function.  I would split each cell into an array then loop through those arrays to find matches then put the matches in the various cells using an offset and a counter to move to the next column. Like this:

```
Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim aRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer, clm As Integer

Set aRng = Range(Range("KW1"), Range("KW1").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In aRng
    a = Split(cel, " ")
    b = Split(cel.Offset(, 1), " ")
    clm = 2

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
            If a(i) = b(t) And a(i) <> "" Then
                cel.Offset(, clm) = a(i)
                clm = clm + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

Next
```

This is case sensitive if you do not want it case sensitive then change the if statement to this

`If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) And a(i) <> "" Then`

Comment: Thanks a lot :)


Its working nicely, however its repeating same words again. Eg: in A column there is a word "Rug" three times means, its searching three times and repeating the same word again. Is there a way to ignore such duplicate words along with skipping case sensitive?

Comment: This is technically a new question, but you need to use a dictionary.  Add each word as it is found to that dictionary and add an if statement before the 'for t' loop testing if the word from the a array exists or not.  [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234) is a good article on how to use a dictionary.  Try to use it and if you can't get it ask a new question with what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks again :). In between words I'm getting blank cells in next columns as a result and I'm wondering why?

Comment: @LingaGuru You may have double spaces in the cells.  It breaks on the single space, thus creating a null entry into the array and if that exists in both you will get the blank column. I will change the code to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Scott i will try dictionary.. :)

Comment: Oh then we can trim it and start working on it right?

Comment: When splitting a string on spaces, which is what we are doing here, there is nothing to trim.  All spaces are removed.  The issue is that we are splitting on a single space.  So if the string is "abc  dgf" with a double space between "abc" and "dgf" then the array gets filled with three strings; "abc","","dgf".  It looks for what is between the single spaces, whether it is nothing or another string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90252/discussion-between-linga-guru-and-scott-craner).